# encryption-decryption error(one time pad encryption)

Tags: c, security, encryption, xor, password-encryption

I fixed some problems with my old code.The problem now is when decrypting a ciphertext already encrypted with my program it gives a word with a letter different than the original one ;so word->encrypted ... then encrypted->decrypted gives decrypted!=word,and even on paper the ciphertext should be different than the one i'm getting.
And an other thing:i tried do{...}while (strlen(...,...)!=0) but it isn't working and tried comparing sizeof also not working. How should i compare the length of the key with the word?

Here is my new code using xor :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define clear_buffer while(getchar()!='\n');
char* encrypt(char texte[],char cle[]){
    char *encrypted;
    int i=0;
    while(texte[i]!='\0' && cle[i]!='\0'){
    if (texte[i] >= 'A' && texte[i] <= 'Z')
    encrypted[i] = ((texte[i] - 'A') ^ (cle[i] - 'A')) % 26 + 'A';
else if (texte[i] >= 'a' && texte[i] <= 'z')
    encrypted[i] = ((texte[i] - 'a') ^ (cle[i] - 'a')) % 26 + 'a';
        i++;
    }
    encrypted[i+1]='\0';
    return encrypted;   

    }
char* decrypt(char encrypted[],char cle[]){
    char *decrypted;
    int i=0;

    while(encrypted[i]!='\0' && cle[i]!='\0'){
    if (encrypted[i] >= 'A' && encrypted[i] <= 'Z')
    decrypted[i] = ((encrypted[i] - 'A') ^ (cle[i] - 'A')) % 26 + 'A';
else if (encrypted[i] >= 'a' && encrypted[i] <= 'z')
    decrypted[i] = ((encrypted[i] - 'a') ^ (cle[i] - 'a')) % 26 + 'a';
        i++;
    }
    decrypted[i+1]=0;
    return decrypted;

}
int main()
{
    char reponse,texte[100],cle[100],encrypted[100];
    int i=0;

    do{
        printf("Voulez vous crypter ou decrypter un texte?(Ecrire C pour crypter et D pour decrypter)\n");
        scanf("%c",&reponse);
    }while (reponse!='C'&& reponse!='D'&& reponse!='c'&& reponse!='d');//controle pour obliger l'utilisateur à donner c ou d
    if(reponse=='C'||reponse=='c'){
            clear_buffer;//vider le buffer apres le scanf de la reponse
                //do{
        printf("Donner un texte a crypter\n");
        fgets(texte,100,stdin);
        while(texte[i]!=0)
            i++;
        if (i>0 && texte[i-1]!='\n')
            clear_buffer;
        printf("Donner une cle de meme taille\n");
        fgets(cle,100,stdin);
            //}while(sizeof texte!=sizeof cle);
        i=0;
        while(cle[i]!=0)
            i++;
        if (i>0 && cle[i-1]!='\n')
            clear_buffer;
        printf("Le texte crypte est:%s\n",encrypt(texte,cle));
    }else{
            clear_buffer;//vider le buffer apres le scanf de la reponse
        //  do{
        printf("Donner un texte (deja crypte) à decrypter\n");
        fgets(encrypted,100,stdin); 
        i=0;
        while(encrypted[i]!=0)
            i++;
        if (i>0 && encrypted[i-1]!='\n')
            clear_buffer;
        printf("Donner la cle (deja utilisee pour crypter\n");
        fgets(cle,100,stdin);
        i=0;
        while(cle[i]!=0)
            i++;
        if (i>0 && cle[i-1]!='\n')
            clear_buffer;
        //}while(sizeof encrypted!=sizeof cle);
        printf("Le texte decrypte est:%s\n",decrypt(encrypted,cle));
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Please* consider using good code formatting standards by indenting your code appropriately. Your code is very difficult to read. Google "C coding standards" if you want some ideas. If you are running Linux, you can use the `indent` command (see `man indent`) to indent your code automatically after the fact. Following good standards will help you follow your own code, too, which facilitates debugging and modifications. Note that the Stackoverflow.com question areas don't support tabs very well. Spaces are recommended instead.

Comment: I just ran `indent` on your code for you. :)

Comment: Thank you very much lurker :)

Comment: is there a tool to indent code online ?

Comment: There is probably an online tool but I don't use them much. You can Google for it. Frankly, the only time I use the tool is when I need to deal with someone else's code and they didn't follow good formatting discipline. You should learn to indent and format nicely while you're writing your code. It will help you read your code as you're creating it.

Comment: It is important when writing C to not ignore warnings. As your code is written the encrypt() and decrypt() return a single char yet you pass then to printf() as format %s which expects a char pointer. You should enable warnings when compiling the code and fix those. You could temporarily change the %s to %c and see if you get past your issue. Then go back and fix those functions if that moved you along.

Comment: johnson i fixed these. Thanks.

Comment: but i am having a problem when running the program:i am getting question marks instea of encrypted text ,it seems the compiler is working with ascii values instead of alphabetical order . How to fix that ?

Comment: @user105453: you should ask a separate question about that. And I suggest that the code you post be reduced to focus just to the problem you ask about.  I'm not sure why a simple question about `fgets()` behavior had more than half the example devoted to encryption and decryption that had nothign to do with the problem being asked about.  For example, in your question about ascii values/alphabetical order (?), you might want to encrypt a string that's in the source code instead of reading it from stdin - I/O will likely have nothing to do with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is scanf left a newline in the buffer for the first fgets to encounter. Don't use scanf for keyboard input; that way lies madness.

Also, this line

```
encrypted = (texte[i] + cle[i]) % 26;
```

is way wrong. Consider what you are trying to do. Perhaps the following:

```
if (texte[i] >= 'A' && texte[i] <= 'Z')
    encrypted = (texte[i] - 'A' + cle[i] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
else if (texte[i] >= 'a' && texte[i] <= 'z')
    encrypted = (texte[i] - 'a' + cle[i] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
```

With the same change for decrypted. Normally it's a bad idea to allow encrypted text to be printable these days, but ...

EDIT: Added - 'A' and - 'a' to both cle[i]

Comment: Thank you. I modified my code. but still showing program not responding:(

Comment: You probably have more problems. Use printf liberally to find out where it hangs up.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the value of encrypted data every time 'i' changes. You can fix that by declaring encrypted as a pointer or a table : `char encrypted[100];`

your code should become :

```
if (texte[i] >= 'A' && texte[i] <= 'Z')
    encrypted[i] = (texte[i] - 'A' + cle[i] - 'A') % 26 + 'A';
else if (texte[i] >= 'a' && texte[i] <= 'z')
    encrypted[i] = (texte[i] - 'a' + cle[i] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';`
```

and if you're planning to use XOR, it will become like this:

```
if (texte[i] >= 'A' && texte[i] <= 'Z')
    encrypted[i] = ((texte[i] - 'A') ^ (cle[i] - 'A')) % 26 + 'A';
else if (texte[i] >= 'a' && texte[i] <= 'z')
    encrypted[i] = ((texte[i] - 'a') ^ (cle[i] - 'a')) % 26 + 'a';`
```

I used some extra parentheses for clarification.

Hopefully that would help.

Comment: I replaced the old code with the new one.It now gives readable letters. But when trying to decrypt an encrypted word it doesn't give the original word(it gives something else:btw it is also using symbols not only letters)

Comment: Your method of encryption and decryption is not optimal. Instead of using the (text + key) and (text - key) technique, try using the Xor. It works as follows: cleartext ^ key = encrypted text and encrypted text ^ key = cleartext. If you still get errors try using printf after every line of instructions so you can verify step by step.

Comment: thank you. but how to use xor for decryption ? with the old way a minus would do it

Comment: XOR or ^ is used the same way in both encryption and decryption. For example: text ^ key gives you an encrypted text using that key. Now if you do the same operation in reverse, which means you replace the text^key with encrypted^key (same key used for encryption), you'll get the decrypted text. If you still didn't understand how it works i suggest you to do a quick research about OTP using XOR.

Comment: ah ok. Thank you man. It worked but still words when encrypted then decrypted show a letter difference.Any idea?

Comment: If you're using something in your text other than the alphabet letters, your current code wont work because it's only written to work between 'a' & 'z' & 'A' & 'Z'. If that's not the case, use printf as i said before to verify if the code is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: i am only using alphabet letters .what do you mean by using printf?where?

Comment: sorry if being very dumb;) i am new to these things

Comment: for example after writing decrypted[i] = ((encrypted[i] - 'a') ^ (cle[i] - 'a')) % 26 + 'a'; use printf to display the result of each decrypted character and see where it goes wrong

Comment: I also noticed that you initialized  char *encrypted; as a pointer but you used it as a table without specifying its size. try initializing it as char encrypted[100]; and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: i can't do so because encrypt & decrypt are functions so it will return one value,it won't take other commands (printf for example)like void. is it right?

Comment: just tried initializing it as table. still the same problem

Comment: procedures are also functions. The only difference between them is that procedures do not return a value, which is why you set it to void. You can use the same commands in both functions and procedures including printf.

Comment: Please ask a different question about the decryption error so you can get helped with the code itself.